# Mobile network related questions

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

Is there a SE site where mobile networking (GSM, LTE etc.) questions related to mobile services can be asked?

I have a specific question to ask:
**Do mobile operators usually offer SLA (service-level agreements) for mobile data services?** Where can I ask this at best?

Also, where can technical details of mobile networking be asked? At Electronics SE? I mean questions like "How does some-subset-of-GSM work?"

Comment: I'd expect "How does GSM work?" to be far too broad to be a fit for any Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Ok, I corrected that to a "subset-of-GSM" to target it better.

Answer (score 3):

Both questions are quite difficult to fit in the SE format. Let's break them down:

1. Do mobile operators offer SLA (service-level agreements) for mobile data services?

   The question is really 'does *any* mobile operator...'. Since there are thousands of them, the question is too broad to fit on any site in the network.
2. How does (some subset of) GSM work?

   There are few GSM standards, so that is not a problem in your question. But really, what is the level of detail you expect? You can write *books* answering the question 'how does GSM work?'. If you can break down that question in smaller pieces it possibly fits on a site in the network, depending how it is formulated. For now, it is too broad.

Comment: #1 I corrected the question to "Do mobile operators _usually_ offer ..." - this is a try to generalize a bit and ask for current (global) state of the thing which may be better than 1000 custom states (as you say). #2 I understand that this is very broad topic.

Comment: Still very hard to answer.

Comment: Yes but hard questions are allowed, right? :) I could not find any info on #1 that is why I want to ask. Or do you mean #1 is still a "bad fit"? I can try to narrow it as much as possible but the general idea has to remain.